# Unable to use pbcopy while in tmux session

Tags: macos, tmux

Running tmux 1.4 installed from ports on snow-leopard I am unable to use the built in OSX `pbcopy` command.

Outside of `tmux`:

```
> echo "abc" | pbcopy
> echo $(pbpaste) # or using ^v
abc
```

But inside of `tmux`:

```
> echo "123" | pbcopy
> echo $(pbpaste)
abc
```

I've scoured the man page but can't find any options that might relate to this behavior.  I also can't understand why `tmux` would mess with shell redirection.

Anybody have any clues?

Comment: Note that this works using `xclip` on Linux. By the way, `echo pbpaste` should result in "pbpaste".

Answer (score 75):

Using homebrew

```
brew install reattach-to-user-namespace --with-wrap-pbcopy-and-pbpaste
```

or Macports

```
sudo port install tmux-pasteboard
```

Prepend the following to the top of ~/.tmux.conf

```
set-option -g default-command "reattach-to-user-namespace -l zsh"
```

You might want to swap out the `zsh` for whichever shell you are using, for portability you should probably use `$SHELL`.

Taken from => 
[robots.thoughtbot.com](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/post/19398560514/how-to-copy-and-paste-with-tmux-on-mac-os-x)

Comment: use `bash` if you're on bash instead of `zsh`

Comment: my bash isn't initialized correctly (.bashrc, .bash_profile not sourced). How should this be done to do that?

Comment: bash_profile will only be sourced by login shells. http://www.joshstaiger.org/archives/2005/07/bash_profile_vs.html

Comment: hey! thanks! I switched my .bashrc with .bash_profile and it worked fine.

Comment: Must enable the option now

    `brew install reattach-to-user-namespace --wrap-pbcopy-and-pbpaste`

Comment: A more robust option for tmux.conf is `set-option -g default-command "reattach-to-user-namespace -l $SHELL"`

Comment: Just a quick note on this for anyone confused like me; it doesn't seem sufficient to enter command mode via _ctrl-b :_ and _:source ~/.tmux.conf_ -- I had to quit the session and restart tmux before it would work.

Comment: I also suggest adding the --wrap-launchctl option, as this is needed for launchctl to work in the same situations.

Comment: option `--wrap-pbcopy-and-pbpaste` was deprecated
using `--with-wrap-pbcopy-and-pbpaste` instead!

Comment: I checked the details at [github.com/ChrisJohnsen/tmux-MacOSX-pasteboard](https://github.com/ChrisJohnsen/tmux-MacOSX-pasteboard) and I had to `tmux kill-server` to get it working on first time.

Answer (score 11):

When `tmux` detaches from the console (in order to support attach/detach), it does so in a way that doesn't allow it to communicate with the GUI any more.

Apple's patches to GNU `screen` use a private system call to detach in a different way. There is a patch in the Macports bug tracker that makes `pbcopy`/`pbpaste` work again. I also submitted it to the Homebrew repo, where it was briefly accepted, then reverted.

This is because when this patch is applied, it causes tmux to crash when re-attaching to a session.

See the [pull request on github](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/pull/3420) for the Homebrew project for more info.

Comment: This would make sense... except that if I run, say, `open .` in a tmux session, it opens a Finder window just fine, so "doesn't allow it to communicate with the GUI any more" doesn't seem quite accurate?

Answer (score 6):

I found a [github project that wraps tmux](https://github.com/ChrisJohnsen/tmux-MacOSX-pasteboard) so that pbpaste and pbcopy work and doesn't have the issues described that caused Homebrew to remove the patch.  It's pretty easy to install, just a small bit of compilation and one line in your .tmux.conf

Homebrew had a patch, but as others mentioned, it was backed out because it caused issues with reattaching.

There was an [issue filed against tmux](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=2960136&group_id=200378&atid=973265), but it was closed because the tmux author doesn't have a Mac to test on.  The README on the github tmux-MacOSX-pasteboard project has great details on why patching tmux is difficult in this case, and a bunch of other info surrounding the situation.  It works on OSX 10.6 for me and reading through the code looks like it will work for 10.5 as well.

Answer (score 3):

This issue is solved with the latest release ( 2.6 ) changelog https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tmux/tmux/2.6/CHANGES .

Answer (score 1):

There is an open ticket here: http://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=2960136&group_id=200378&atid=973265

> Date: 2010-02-28 11:20:57 UTC
>   Sender: nicm
>
> **There is no reason you can't just pipe tmux showb to it, of course.**
>
> Date: 2010-02-28 11:20:05 UTC
>   Sender: nicm
>
> Not unless someone sends me some code to do it or some hardware with OS X
>   on it.

I tried piping showb to pbcopy and it didn't work.

```
~: echo "12345"
12345
[use copy-mode to copy "12345"]
~: tmux showb
12345
~: tmux showb | pbcopy
~: pbpaste
```

Answer (score 1):

I use [tmux-MacOSX-pasteboard](https://github.com/ChrisJohnsen/tmux-MacOSX-pasteboard) on both Snow Leopard and Lion and it patches pbcopy/pbpaste functionality for you in tmux. Easy to install, too.

Comment: tmux-MacOSX-pasteboard is now in macports as well with tmux-pasteboard name